Drag and drop problem in my javascript exercise
This is a "draggable todoList" exercise and there's a problem with "drophandler" part and i know what's the problem but i can't solve it!
There are multiple columns on the page that I want my "todo"s to be dropped in those columns. And if there are several todos, I can drop each one in any column I want. I would be grateful if you could help me solve the problem :)
The problem is that when I add several todos, because the todos are an array, I don't know how to access each index of these todos. I tried to use foreach but I got error.
It seems that the problem is in the "targetElm" variable because the value inside this variable is of the HTMLCollection type, so i don't know exactly what to do here.


// default
const $ = document;

function dragOverHandler(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
}

// modal objects
const modalBox = $.querySelector('.modal')
const closeModalBtn = $.querySelector('.close-modal');
let todoInput = $.querySelector('#todo_input');
let todoSubmit = $.querySelector('#todo_submit');
let errMsg = $.querySelector('.msg');
const columns = $.querySelectorAll('.status');

// add todo btn
const addTodoBtn = $.querySelector('#add_btn');

// no status column - ( default )
const noStatusCol = $.querySelector('#no_status');

// modal show and modal hide
function showModal() {
  modalBox.classList.add('active');
}

function hideModal() {
  modalBox.classList.remove('active');
}

// Add todo
function addTodo() {
  let todoInputValue = todoInput.value;
  if (todoInputValue) {

    // create a todo
    let newTodo = $.createElement('div');
    newTodo.className = 'todo';
    newTodo.setAttribute('draggable', 'true');
    newTodo.textContent = todoInputValue;

    let newTodoClose = $.createElement('span');
    newTodoClose.innerHTML = '&times;';
    newTodoClose.className = 'close';

    newTodo.append(newTodoClose);
    noStatusCol.append(newTodo);

    // remove a todo
    newTodoClose.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
      event.target.parentElement.remove();
    })

    // dragstart on todos
    newTodo.addEventListener('dragstart', function(event) {
      event.dataTransfer.setData('elementClass', event.target.className);
    });

    hideModal();
  } else {
    errMsg.textContent = 'Please fill in the input field';
    todoInput.style.border = '1px solid red';
    errMsg.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

// drophandler part
columns.forEach(function(col) {
  col.addEventListener('drop', function(event) {

    let targetCls = event.dataTransfer.getData('elementClass');
    let targetElm = $.getElementsByClassName(targetCls);
    event.target.append(targetElm[ ? ]);

  });
});

addTodoBtn.addEventListener('click', showModal);
closeModalBtn.addEventListener('click', hideModal);
todoSubmit.addEventListener('click', addTodo);

todoInput.addEventListener('keypress', function() {
  errMsg.textContent = '';
  errMsg.style.display = 'none';
  todoInput.style.border = '1px solid rgb(64, 141, 64)';
});
<!-- modal -->
<div class="modal" id="todo_form">

  <div class="header">
    <div class="title">Add Todo</div>
    <button class="btn close-modal">&times;</button>
  </div>

  <div class="body">
    <input type="text" id="todo_input" />
    <span class="msg"></span>
    <input type="submit" value="Add Todo" id="todo_submit" />
  </div>

</div>

<!-- todo -->
<div class="todo-container">

  <div class="status" id="no_status">
    <h1>No Status</h1>
    <button id="add_btn" data-target-modal="#todo_form">+ Add Todo</button>

    <!--<div class="todo" draggable="true">
          Buy a Pizza
          <span class="close">&times;</span>
        </div>-->

  </div>

  <div ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);" class="status">
    <h1>Not Started</h1>
  </div>

  <div ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);" class="status">
    <h1>In Progress</h1>
  </div>

  <div ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);" class="status">
    <h1>Completed</h1>
  </div>

</div>

<div id="overlay"></div>




If targetElm is an HTMLCollection, then you need some way to determine which element in the collection is the actual target.

event.target.append(targetElm[ ? ]); certainly gives an error

So get the ID: let targetID = event.dataTransfer.getData('id'); and have data-id="aUniqueID"
